# Chrome App: use chrome.cookies

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I already have a Chrome extension which use `chrome.cookies` API's. (See [Chrome Cookies API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies))

Is there an equivalent to manage cookies (get, remove..) in a Chrome app?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

At most, you control the lifetime of cookies in a `<webview>` tag by selecting a partition, or by expressly clearing them.